# How do you copy and paste large pdfs?

Tags: pdf, copy-paste, clipboard, ctrl

Copy and paste doesn't work on pdf files. I have a windows 10 machine. When I try ctrl+a'ing, copying, and pasting an entire 400 page document, it HIGHLIGHTS everything, but when I copy , I notice that my cpu gives little effort and sure enough, when I paste, I figure out that it just decided to randomly take a small chunk off of a couple of pages. (This same sort of thing also happens with ctrl+F , but that's beside the point)

How can I make copy and paste work like it should on these bigger files? I'm using firefox to view it if that helps. I've also tried changing the clipboard size to be custom but that didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: You're using Firefox for what? I assume you mean you use Firefox to view the PDF but please edit the post to make this clear. Also, trying a different PDF viewer seems to me a key part of diagnosis and likely resolution also.

Comment: I've also tried using google drive to open the pdf, and i've also tried copying it as a doc. It keeps doing this thing where it just randomly selects some text that my cursor was near (even though I can see that control+a highlighted everything) and then pasting the randomly selected text. Someone asked a question like this a while ago and they were offered a firefox extension, but that particular extension was removed.

Comment: Note that PDF doesn't really contain "text", but is a rendering language that describes how glyphs and graphics are positioned on the page. For simple PDFs, you can reconstruct text from that (or from whatever Firefox renders), and then use copy&paste on it. For complex PDFs, this may fail. There are command-line tools to extract text from PDFs, if that's what you need. Keeping the formatting will be difficult in general.

Comment: @dirkt How can I reconstruct text? What did you mean by that?

Comment: Use the EDIT button please, to add requested information to your question to improve it.

Comment: @dirkt PDFs can be either. If you took a document and "printed" it directly into a PDF it will contain text information. If you scan a page into a PDF it will be an image. You could run OCR on this to retrieve certain information but any changes in layout or issues with transcription will result in errors in this process.

Comment: @music2myear I did, so do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm pretty sure I was able to get this done with an extractor (kudos dirkt) from pdfcandy.com . Really interesting, because my cpu used very little power (really! like 2 or 3 percent) when copying and pasting the 400 pages among text files, but used nearly 70% when I pasted it on a google doc. Weird. Thanks again

Comment: @music2myear Even if it's not scanned, it **never** contains "text" information. Go read the spec. It contains the glyphs, and if you are lucky, also tables that allow to recover what text is needed to produce which glyphs. On top of that, if you are lucky and the program you use to "print" keeps the layout (mostly), you can also recover the layout. I could make you a PDF file without a single image, where it's hopeless to recover the text, because it uses custom embedded fonts, and all the above information is missing.